# VB.NET - Why is the secondary form closing?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

In vb.net, whenever I click my button "ok", it also closes the second form? And please slap me if I have done a school boy error here. I just do not understand what is going on.

```
 Private Sub btOk_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btOk.Click
       Close()
        Dim frmMainScreen As New frmMain

        frmMainScreen.Show()
 end sub
```

Comment: You probably want your `Close` after the code to show the MainScreen

Comment: @MattWilko pitty u cant hand out slaps lol one of those momments

Comment: if the second form is frmMainScreen, then when you Close whatever form this code is in, the form goes away along with the code you want to run

Comment: Plutonix is right. Use Me.Hide() instead

Comment: you may want the form to have a scope larger than just that click event too, especially if you have code which will reference it

Answer (score 1):

You first have to show the new form, and then have to close the old form.

Default settings in your application is closing when last form closed. So if you close the actual form (which is the last i think) then your application closes complete.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Alex you have to change the project properties *(Application Tab => Shutdown mode => Select: "When last form closes")* first, but also you need to change your code to be:

```
 Private Sub btOk_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btOk.Click
        Dim frmMainScreen As New frmMain
        frmMainScreen.Show()
        Close()
 End Sub
```

Show the second form then close the previous one.

[image]

Comment: What project property?

Comment: This still won't work. The OP created an instance of a form in the `btOk_Click` event. Once he closes the current form, frmMainScreen will be out of scope and will die, and therefore also closes.

Comment: @DejaVu thank you i didnt notice that sorry budy im from the uk must be time difference between us